# How to add stroke in content of textview in android

Tags: android, text, textview, stroke

[image]

I do not want to use image resource. The text in the textview should be like above image.Is there any way possible to do this style either in xml or in java/kotlin code. Also I dont want to use canvas painting. please help.

Comment: use font instead of creating xml.

Comment: @HemantParmar I have used external font, but how to change that color of stroke?

Comment: just change your  text color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found somewhere on Internet. I have created a custom textview and in onDraw method have used the below code, which uses canvas drawing to create the Text Outline of textview effect.

```
 override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    if(strokeColor!=null)
    {
        val textColor = textColors

        val paint = this.paint

        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.strokeJoin = strokeJoin
        paint.strokeMiter = strokeMiter    //10f
        this.setTextColor(strokeColor)
        paint.strokeWidth = strokeWidth    //15f

        super.onDraw(canvas)
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL

        setTextColor(textColor)
        super.onDraw(canvas)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution

Comment: delete this solution or fix it, it will loop `onDraw` method forever, recursive

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this [library](https://github.com/biomorgoth/android-outline-textview)

**Example**

```
<com.biomorgoth.outlinetextview.StrokedTextView
        android:id="@+id/your_text_view"
        android:text="I am a StrokedTextView!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        strokeAttrs:textStrokeColor="@android:color/black"
        strokeAttrs:textStrokeWidth="1.7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Example 2**

```
<com.biomorgoth.outlinetextview.StrokedEditText
        android:id="@+id/your_edit_text"
        android:hint="Write here!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#5fff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        strokeAttrs:textStrokeColor="@android:color/black"
        strokeAttrs:textStrokeWidth="1.7"
        strokeAttrs:textHintStrokeColor="#5000"
        strokeAttrs:textHintStrokeWidth="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```